# wordpress control panel login problems

Tags: wordpress, authentication, control-panel

I have a blog that was built with word press. when I want to login into control panel it redirect me to this page:

```
http://tweld.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Ftweld.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

One time I Uninstalled word press files and then uploaded again. after that it worked correctly. but this problem has arisen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of this codex guide: `http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble`

have a look in your error logs at your hosts backend.

try:

1. logout or logout with `http://www.yourdomain.com/wp-login.php?action=logout`
2. disable all plugins
3. clear cookies/cache
4. exit browser

just for troubleshooting purposes try:
- switching to the default theme by renaming your current theme's folder in wp-content/themes using FTP or whatever file management application your host provides.

- resetting the plugins folder by using FTP or whatever file management application your host provides. Sometimes, an apparently inactive plugin can still cause problems.
- renaming or deleting the .htaccess file after making a backup of this file
- Check your .htaccess and wp-config.php if they are correct

[source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-admin-suddenly-not-working#post-2149818)